# Angular CLI install hangs and times out on Windows 11 with 'Invalid response body' error

Tags: installation, angular-cli

node version: 18.16.0
npm version: 9.6.7

When I did  npm install -g @angular/cli
it runs through a number of steps and then stalls and times out.

I looked at the error log and it suggested it was a neta work problem.

I asked Verizon to check my network and it is fine ( 1Gig speed).
I used my laptop and the installation ran without a problem.
Both used the same router.

This is a new PC; everything is installed from the ground up.

NEXT I tried to do the installation like this:

1. From the LAPTOP, I copied the following:
   C:\users<my id>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular
2. I pasted in on the PC in the corresponding location overwriting the existing @angular.
3. I then ran the following command:
   npm install -g --cache ./.npm-cache @angular/cli
   This ran and then got the same error shown here:
   [CMD Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDDKL.jpg)
   The error log file is quite long, here is where the error is described:

```
1024 timing idealTree:fixDepFlags Completed in 1ms
1025 timing idealTree Completed in 23246ms
1026 timing command:install Completed in 23287ms
1027 verbose type system
1028 verbose stack FetchError: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer: read ECONNRESET
1028 verbose stack     at C:\Users\princ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\body.js:170:15
1028 verbose stack     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
1028 verbose stack     at async Response.json (C:\Users\princ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\minipass-fetch\lib\body.js:75:17)
1028 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.packument (C:\Users\princ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:94:25)
1028 verbose stack     at async RegistryFetcher.manifest (C:\Users\princ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\pacote\lib\registry.js:118:23)
1028 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 0)
1028 verbose stack     at async #buildDepStep (C:\Users\princ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:1034:5)
1028 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (C:\Users\princ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\build-ideal-tree.js:196:7)
1028 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (C:\Users\princ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\reify.js:159:5)
1028 verbose stack     at async Install.exec (C:\Users\princ\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\commands\install.js:147:5)
1029 verbose cwd C:\Users\princ
1030 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.22621
1031 verbose node v18.16.0
1032 verbose npm  v9.6.7
1033 error code ECONNRESET
1034 error syscall read
1035 error errno ECONNRESET
1036 error network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer: read ECONNRESET
1037 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
1037 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
1037 error network
1037 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
1037 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
1038 verbose exit 1
1039 timing npm Completed in 23550ms
1040 verbose unfinished npm timer reify 1685198656917
1041 verbose unfinished npm timer reify:loadTrees 1685198656956
1042 verbose code 1
1043 error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\princ\.npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-27T14_44_16_656Z-debug-0.log
```

I don't have a proxy (it's my home PC).
I believe this means I have a problem with network settings.
I don't see a problem and I don't have a connection issue with any other site.

Thanks in Advance :-)

I included information about what I did to try to solve the problem in the previous description. I have searched the web and asked two chatbots  LOL.